# How to convert DTED MSL values to ellipsoid height

Tags: geotiff-tiff, dted

I have ALOS3D TIFF files with height values. I understand it is MSL height values.
I would like to convert the whole file into a new TIFF file with WGS84 ellipsoid heights.
The ALOS3D files is EPSG 4326, and I would like to keep it the same in the result TIFF.

How do I go about it?